# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, html

Im having this html script for a calculator App, with added buttons to click.
I want to use eventLister to get the button clicked by the user but I'm not able to do so.
Im getting
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
init (script.js:86:43)
at script.js:93:1
in console.

```
<body>
    
     <div class="wrapper">
        <section class="screen">
            0
        </section>
        <section class="calc-buttons">
            <div class="calc-button-row">
                <button class = "calc-button double">C</button>
                <button class="calc-button">&larr;</button>
                <button class="calc-button">&divide;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="calc-button-row">
                <button class="calc-button">7</button>
                <button class="calc-button">8</button>
                <button class="calc-button">9</button>
                <button class="calc-button">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="calc-button-row">
                <button class="calc-button">4</button>
                <button class="calc-button">5</button>
                <button class="calc-button">6</button>
                <button class="calc-button">&minus;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="calc-button-row">
                <button class="calc-button">1</button>
                <button class="calc-button">2</button>
                <button class="calc-button">3</button>
                <button class="calc-button">&plus;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="calc-button-row">
                <button class="calc-button triple">0</button>
                <button class="calc-button">&equals;</button>
            </div>
        </section>
     </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

In script.js I'm using,

```
function init() {
    document.querySelector('calc-buttons').
        addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log(event, "event in init")
            buttonClick(event.target.innerText);
        })
}
console.log('here')
init();
```

to capture the button clicked but its throwing error in eventListners.
Can someone help fix the issue?

Comment: In the querySelector('calc-buttons') you forgot the dot to call the class, its : 
`document.querySelector('.calc-buttons')`

Answer (score 3):

You need to let [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) know, if the entered string is a class name ('.calc-buttons') or an id ('#calc-buttons').

Also, you are selecting the section tag when you use `document.querySelector('.calc-buttons')`

If you want to select all buttons, you need to use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.calc-button')
```

And then you need to loop through the buttons to add event listeners to all buttons. For example like this:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.calc-button')
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        buttonClick(event.target.innerText);
    })
}
```

So, the whole thing would look like this:

```
function init() {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.calc-button')
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log(event, "event in init")
            buttonClick(event.target.innerText);
        })
    }
}
console.log('here')
init();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you forgot the dot before the class name in the querySelector :
The correct code is :

```
function init() {
    document.querySelector('.calc-buttons')
        .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log(event, "event in init")
            buttonClick(event.target.innerText);
        });
}

console.log('here');
init();
```